# I want to start the scheduler at 12 am

Tags: node.js

For the first time only, I want to start the scheduler at 12 am. after that it will automatically schedule the job for every 4 hours. Now the job is running for every 4 hrs only.

```
schedule.scheduleJob("00 04 * * *" , function(req, res){
return new promise(function(fulfill, reject){
var ind= info;
var output = [];
for(var i = 0; i < ind.length; i++) {
    var data = ind[i].code;
    console.log("Data: " + data);
    var request = require('request'),,
        headers = {
                    "Content-type":"application/json"
                  };
    var options = {     
        host : config.host,
        path : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' + data,
        port : config.port,
        method : 'POST',
        headers : headers
    };  
console.log(options);
operation(options,function(err, resultCode, result){
    trace.info('resultCode:' + resultCode); 
            });
        }
    });
});
```

How to change the code to work as expected? I tried the Timeout concept, but it is not working.

Comment: What is the package you are using? I would have 2 jobs. The first is scheduled at 12am and only run once. This job then schedule the second job which running every 4 hours

Comment: I got the answer.. Now am using SetInterval(). Issue Fixed. Thank You!